# the use of library functions in pic code

Tags: assembly

is this code PIC(position independant)?
as long as i know there must be no library functions in PIC code, but i am not sure that printf here considered as a library function.

also, after executing this code what is the value in edx register?
is it the absolute address of to_printf or printf or is it the difference of addresses of to_printf and next_i?

```
to_printf: dd printf
get_my_loc:
call next_i
next_i: 
pop edx
ret
call get_my_loc
push edx
add edx, (to_print - next_i)
```

Comment: Oh - you mean Position Independent Code - not PIC as in the popular micro-controller, right ?

Comment: yes i mean Position Independent Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

absolute address, identical to address of label next_i the first time you run into subroutine next_i.  after ret,
"push edx" is executed, with edx still containing the address of instruction "pop edx"

```
sequence of execution   effect
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
call get_my_loc                addr of next instruction (push edx) stacked. call it "addr1"     
call next_i                          addr of next instruction (pop edx) stacked.  "addr2"
pop edx                             addr2 -> edx
ret                                      continues at addr1. addr2 was popped already.
; next operations work on edx, containing addr2, pointing to "pop edx"             
push edx    
add edx, ...
```

Comment: i didnt completely understand your answer

Comment: but edx contains the absolute address of what? to_printf? ro printf?

Comment: "absolute address" referred to "stacked return address" which was what i originally understood you were asking, because of pulling the return address - meaning return address is not stored as displacement, but as address readily loadable into program counter.  Relocating code changes the value of that address according where code is executed. Subtracting the absolute difference between those two labels from edx (or, adding the negative absolute difference, as you do) results in edx point to dd printf - assuming you mean "to_printf" where you wrote "to_print"